# tomcat 8 : Wrong interpretation of message "java.util.Arrays.stream(Unknown Source)"

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

(I'm new to tomcat, so I made my best guess at what coudld be happening for the title ; I'll edit it if it doesn't match)

I have a tomcat 8, with java 8 orcale running both on debian and win7.
I have a servlet that runs correctly on the debian install, and uses 
Array.stream()
I copied the .class to the win7 install, and got this message

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> java.util.Arrays.stream(Unknown Source)

I checked my JAVA_HOME on win7 and it does point to my java8
I tried to use Arrays.stream() on my eclipse mars, on win7, and it worked.

I guess something is wrong with my tomcat8 configuration.
it's a win service, out of the box, I mean straight from the apache install.

any clue on what could be going on?

thanks

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace from the tomcat log. `NullPointerException` indicates something wrong in you app, but java version seems to be correct...

Comment: This isn't likely to be a version thing. The exception doesn't say `NoSuchMethodError`, it says `NullPointerException`. So, are you passing-in a null parameter or something like that?

Comment: dedel, christopher, hi. I'll only have access to the win7 machine only on monday, but if I get it you're saying that I missunderstood the "java.util.Arrays.stream(Unknown Source)" : it doesn't mean that the stream() method was not available. is that right ? if it's so, then it gives me the idea that the problem might come from something like the path syntax difference between win and linux, and thus the null pointer. I'll check that out and give you the feed back as soon as I get my hands on the win7 machine. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `--StartMode=java` commandline parameter. Another option in tomcat 8 as a service is to take a java.dll which might not be java 8. See also: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

thanks to dedek and christopher:

you were both right : my interpretation of "java.util.Arrays.stream(Unknown Source)" was wrong. it's just a null pointer exception, due to path difference in linux and windows

I edited the title to reflect that